# WordPress Twenty Twelve Child Theme. Removing default widgetized areas

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

I'm trying to remove Main Sidebar, First and Second Front Page Widget areas in my child theme. Basically I don't want them to be shown up in Admin Panel.

I've placed that code into my function.php file. It's seems to not work:

```
function remove_some_widgets(){

    unregister_sidebar( 'Main Sidebar' );
    unregister_sidebar( 'First Front Page Widget Area' );
    unregister_sidebar( 'Secon Front Page Widget Area' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widgets', 11 );
```

I've got it from [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar) but I think that was developed for Twenty Ten theme. Anyone knows the right code for Twenty Twelve parent theme. ?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [unregister_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar) takes the `ID`, not the `name`:

```
<?php unregister_sidebar( $id ); ?>
```

You'll need to do it like this:

```
<?php
function remove_some_widgets(){
    unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
    unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' );
    unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widgets', 11 );
?>
```